# Is it smart to use clientside JavaScript to transform a HTML page instead of sending multiple HTML pages from a server?

Tags: javascript, html

If I were to have a web server that sent out a html, js and css document to a person and upon them clicking on "Contact Us" from the "Home" page I would have JS to change certain parts of the content and possibly push fake history (I think this is possible but I might not remember right) instead of requesting a new HTML page specially made on the server.

Wouldn't this be much better for my web server due to less GET requests? Would there be any major problems with doing this? Any examples of sites that use client-side page changing?

Comment: For further reading: What you're describing is a fairly minimal kind of *single page application*. There are indeed benefits (and costs/issues).

Comment: You've just described an AJAX application.
You could 'push' html blocks to page area's with Jquery's Ajax implementation quite easily .. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Thanks I will read up on this - wasn't sure what to search for!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Wouldn't this be much better for my web server due to less GET requests?

No. HTTP requests aren't that expensive. You'd probably end up sending more data anyway (since you have to send the data for all the pages on the first request, and visitors might not event look at them all).

> Would there be any major problems with doing this?

You either:

- Do a **lot** of work *or*
- You have a JS dependent, search engine unfriendly site

> Any examples of sites that use client-side page changing?

Github's file viewer does it. (They take the "lot of work" approach).

Comment: That first point on the data requests is really good. Thank you, Quentin. I will look into some further reading that people are suggesting but this does seem like quite a deal breaker.